# How to open URL in CSV file and input data one by one python script

Tags: python, selenium, automation

I'm trying to create a script that will open a URL in a CSV file and input the same information, close the browser and open the 2nd URL inputting the same data. I

```
import csv
import webbrowser

file = open('mycsvfile.csv','r')
reader = csv.reader(file)
for row reader:
   webbrowser.open_new(row[0])
```

I know this will open all the URLs in my csv file. Is there a way I can open a url, input my data. close the URL and repeat the process with the 2nd URL in the row?

Comment: use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) instead of `webbrower`. With `webbrowser` you can only open file in browser but you can't control this browser to input data. With [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) you can control web browser and you can input data.

Answer (score 2):

With the added help of selenium and looping through as normal, we're able to navigate to each url within our csv file. You could try the following :)

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium import webdriver
from csv import reader


def main(handler):

    """ Start firefox instance """
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()

    for row in handler:
        """ Navigate to url """
        driver.get(str(row[0]))
        """ Input data """
        driver.find_element_by_id("someId").send_keys("someData")
        """ Close browser """
        driver.close()

    print("Completed!")

if __name__ == '__main__':

    """ Read from CSV """
    with open('mycsvfile.csv') as file:
        handler = reader(file)
        main(handler)
```